# How to design relationship for racing team trades?

Tags: database-design, schema, normalization

I'm working on a fantasy racing team project. I'm having trouble laying out the schema when it comes to the `team` table and the trades. I think I have the `race`, `driver`, and `result` tables laid out okay:

[image: Fantasy Racing Team Schema]

Each team has to have 10 drivers; two in group one, three in group two, and five in group three.

Each team may have two trades throughout the season. The traded and obtained columns are there so I can calculate who is on a team at a specific race (or point in time). For example, if there were three races and `driver_1_1` was traded away after the first race, the team would only get that driver's points for the first race. For the last two races they would get points from the driver that `driver_1_1` was traded for.

I have a strong feeling that the `team` table can be done in a much better way, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it, especially because of the trades. Please help me normalize!

If it matters I'm planning on using the latest Django Python and PostgreSQL.

**EDIT:**

Here's a simplified version of the schema without all of the fluff. I've also gotten rid of the hard coded driver columns and replaced them with a `pick` table. There's still the matter of the trades, and whether or not this is the right way to go about something something like this. Better?

[image: Is this better?]

Comment: Almost half of the `team` table is devoted to trading of some sort. Can you explain what that is about and why there are "hard-coded" driver positions? These columns seem like they should be rows in a new table but I don't understand the domain.

Comment: The `traded` and `obtained` columns are there so I can calculate who is on a team at a specific race (or point in time). For example, if there were three races and `driver_1_1` was traded away after the first race, the team would only get that driver's points for the first race. For the last two races they would get points from the driver that `driver_1_1` was traded for.

Comment: I've also updated my question with a picks table that replaces the hard-coded driver columns. Is this the right way to go about something like this?

Comment: This looks much, much better. The queries might be a bit complex, but that just reflects the complexity of the problems you're trying to solve.